# Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0 when i try to add mobile-center-push to React Native project

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

I want integrate the push notification to my React Native project follow the guide
https://mobile.azure.com/orgs/....../push/setup
and when i run

```
react-native run-android
```

i got an error:

```
-> % react-native run-android
Scanning 744 folders for symlinks in /Users/kalaliu/temp/RNBase/node_modules (5ms)
JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
File /Users/kalaliu/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':mobile-center-push'.
      > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':mobile-center-push:_debugPublishCopy'.
         > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0.
           Required by:
               RNBase:mobile-center-push:unspecified > com.microsoft.azure.mobile:mobile-center-push:0.10.0
         > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0.
           Required by:
               RNBase:mobile-center-push:unspecified > com.microsoft.azure.mobile:mobile-center-push:0.10.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

it looks like that i need upgrade my android SDK in my RN project?
any idea about this?
my android configuration

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rnbase"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.1"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

my package.json

```
"mobile-center": "^0.6.0",
"mobile-center-analytics": "^0.6.0"
"mobile-center-crashes": "^0.6.0",
"mobile-center-push": "^0.7.0",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "^0.45.1",
```

PS:
i find the firebase tips:
[image: if i upgrade my local SDK, this is a safe update for React Native?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebase SDK is in a local repository that you need to update if outdated:

[image]

Comment: I can upgrade my local SDK and do this mean i should upgrade my build.gradle. "compileSdkVersion 23" to other version, does this safe for React Native?

Comment: You should read this then: https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a step related to Firebase. Please make sure that you have completed all steps of the instructions.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile-center/sdk/push/react-native-android#prerequisite---add-firebase-to-your-app):

> Before using Mobile Center Push service, you need to add Firebase to your application.